# Mac -- disable "You have forced [appname] to quit" popup?

Tags: mac, popups

I don't want to see that popup anymore.  I could not care less if it transmits my data or not.  But I don't want to see the popup whenever I kill the app.  Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none`